# Algorithm to check if two boxes overlap

Tags: algorithm

I have understood the algorithm in case of rectangles but I am confused with the boxes with x, y, z and height as value given. The conditions for not overlapping are
1) Box A above Box B
2) Box A below Box B
3) Box A left of Box B
4) Box A right of Box B

Am I correct? Please guide some missing points.

Comment: You need also to check if it's behind or in front. 6 checks.

Comment: x,y,z **and** height? So 4 dimensions? Usually z is height, or x, or y. Or just x,y and z?

Comment: @ariel thanks.. ya 6 checks

Comment: @Dukeling Ya z axis is height usually but I read a question like this so confused.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Two axes aligned boxes (of any dimension) overlap if and only if the projections to all axes overlap. The projection to an axis is simply the coordinate range for that axis.

[image]

The blue and the green boxes in the image above overlap because their projections to both axes overlap. The blue and the orange box do not overlap, because their projections to the x-axis do not overlap (note that their projections to the y-axis *do* overlap). The green and the orange box do not overlap, because their projections to the y-axis don't overlap (while their projections to the x-axis do overlap).

So when it comes to code for 1D boxes (intervals) we have:

```
box1 = (xmin1, xmax1)
box2 = (xmin2, xmax2)
isOverlapping1D(box1,box2) = xmax1 >= xmin2 and xmax2 >= xmin1
```

For 2D boxes (rectangles) we have:

```
box1 = (x:(xmin1,xmax1),y:(ymin1,ymax1))
box2 = (x:(xmin2,xmax2),y:(ymin2,ymax2))
isOverlapping2D(box1,box2) = isOverlapping1D(box1.x, box2.x) and 
                             isOverlapping1D(box1.y, box2.y)
```

For 3D boxes we have:

```
box1 = (x:(xmin1,xmax1),y:(ymin1,ymax1),z:(zmin1,zmax1))
box2 = (x:(xmin2,xmax2),y:(ymin2,ymax2),z:(zmin2,zmax2))
isOverlapping3D(box1,box2) = isOverlapping1D(box1.x, box2.x) and 
                             isOverlapping1D(box1.y, box2.y) and
                             isOverlapping1D(box1.z, box2.z)
```

Comment: Ready to use one-liner: `isOverlapping = (x1min < x2max AND x2min < x1max AND y1min < y2max AND y2min < y1max)` (add z's if you need them, switch to `<=` if you want to call a 'tangency' an overlap)

Comment: `isOverlapping = (x1min < x2max && x2min < x1max && y1min < y2max && y2min < y1max)` ... that's more like it

Comment: Question for this thread: if xmax1 >= xmin2 and xmax2 >= xmin1 do we even need to check the other axises to see if the boxes intersect? I know I'm missing something obvious, but can someone give me an example where two boxes don't intersect on the x-axis (xmax1 >= xmin2 and xmax2 >= xmin1 evaluate to false) but do on either the y-axis or z-axis?

Comment: @jmb7438 the above orange box and green box intersect on the x-axis, but do not intersect on the y-axis, so overall they do not intersect

Comment: @coproc Duh. Thank you! Lol I knew I was missing something obvious

Comment: WARNING: The above conditions are correct provided you are working in the 1st Quadrant of Cartesian Coordinate System!

Comment: @AnuragBhalekar these conditions work in any quadrant. The conditions do not contain any abs or sign or comparison to zero, which makes them work along all axes over the whole range.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(xMin1 <= xMax2 || xMax1 >= xMin2)
 
if(yMin1 <= yMax2 || yMax1 >= yMin2)

if(zMin1 <= zMax2 || zMax1 >= zMin2)
```

All of these conditions have to be true for the boxes to not be overlapped.

Also I assumed that the box edges could lay on the same x,y,z co-ordinates.

If not, just take the equal signs outs.

```
if(xMin1 < xMax2 || xMax1 > xMin2)
 
if(yMin1 < yMax2 || yMax1 > yMin2)

if(zMin1 < zMax2 || zMax1 > zMin2)
```

Comment: You need AND not OR (I read `||` as OR): `isOverlapping = (x1min < x2max AND x2min < x1max AND y1min < y2max AND y2min < y1max)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by checking whether two extents are not NOT intersecting, ie. the two extents are disjoint.

If the max X of A is smaller then min X of B they can NOT be intersecting.

If the min X of A is bigger then max X of B they can NOT be intersecting.

If the max Y of A is smaller then min Y of B they can NOT be intersecting.

If the min Y of A is bigger then max Y of B they can NOT be intersecting.

```js
A = [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]
B = [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]

// True if intersecting
!(A[0] > B[2] || A[2] < B[0] || A[1] > B[3] || A[3] < B[1])
```