# Postgres: Check if two boxes overlap

Tags: stored-procedures, constraints, overlap, database-trigger, postgresql-9.4

I currently have the following tables in a database:

```
create table map (
    id          bigint          not null unique,
    zone        box             not null,
    ...
    primary key(id)
);

create table other_map (
    id          bigint          not null unique,
    zone        box             not null,
    ...
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(id) references map(id)
);
```

I don't want to allow a new row to be inserted in `other_map` if there is a row in `map` whose `id` is equal to the new entry's `id` **and** their `zone` attributes overlap. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925818/algorithm-to-check-if-two-boxes-overlap), which explains how to detect overlapping boxes, but I'd like to know how to (best) apply that in Postgres.

This is what I've come up with so far, using a trigger and a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PROC_other_map_IU()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $PROC_other_map_IU$
DECLARE
    id      bigint;
    zone    box;
BEGIN
    SELECT map.id, map.zone INTO id, zone
    FROM map
    WHERE map.id = NEW.id;

    IF zone = NEW.zone THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION '%\'s zone overlaps with existing %\'s zone', NEW.id, id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$PROC_other_map_IU$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER TR_other_map_IU
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON other_map
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE PROC_other_map_IU();
```

Now obviously this is wrong, because it simply checks if the `zone` attributes are equal.

Thank you in advance for your input! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while, but Postgres' [geometric functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-geometry.html) (more specifically the `&&` - or overlap - operator) do exactly what I wanted:

```
IF zone && NEW.zone THEN
```

Comment: The so-called "overlap" operator also returns true if they are just _touching_, e.g. `box '(0,0),(1,1)' && box '(0,1),(1,2)'` => `t`.  The box overlap `#` operator is the same. I don't see any way to check for overlap _without_ touching.